# Angular 2- Add Annotation in ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf.js

I'm using **[ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer)** to view pdf in browser using  Angular 2.
I'm new to Angular 2.0.

I want to use/add Annotation functionality in the pdf with the help of current library(ng2-pdf-viewer) which is based on mozilla/pdf.js.So what configuration do i need to make?

If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: use/add Annotation functionality in the pdf means?

Comment: means i can annotate(Put some comments on selected text) some text in open pdf as we do in normal pdfs.

Comment: maybe a piece of answer : https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-annotations